# Canon camera is not detected in gphoto2?

Tags: android

I have used gphoto2 for integrating digital camera integration through android device. I have build the application in linux and able to run it also but when I connected the digital camera of canon i.e canon EOS 5D Mark II it doesn't detect it. When I click on detect camera button it shows 0 camera detected. I am unable to find the problem please help.? 
I got gphoto from this site i.e http://gitorious.org/agphoto2/agphoto2/trees/master

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You ought to specify your Linux distribution and version, and how the connection is made, possibly with steps to reproduce.

As far as I understand, Canon EOS support is still somewhat immature, and possibly a gphoto upgrade (or downgrade), or a different distribution (you may try to run it from a Live CD and see what happens) might help.

This guy here started having problems after an Ubuntu upgrade, apparently, so driver/kernel might be an issue:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gphoto2/+bug/1009955